# Metaanalysis and influence analysis

Tags: r, meta-analysis

I am currently performing a meta-analysis of hazard ratios (HR) in the R studio. Given high degree of the between-study heterogeneity (I² was around 65%), I have decided to perform influence analysis to possibly identify the reason of that heterogeneity.

However, I got very confusing results. By looking at the forest plot, I would say one particular study would be outlier / influential.

[image: This is the forest plot].

However, using InfluenceAnalysis in R, I got results completely the other way around. I am pretty sure the code is right, because in other meta analyses everything worked well. Do you think, that all but one observation can be actually overly influential?

[image: This is the plot of influence analysis].

EDIT: I have one more information, which may help. If I use fixed-effects instead of random-effects the problem resolves; however, this is really not how this should be done ...

Comment: I am afraid I do not see what the problem is here. What are your criteria for declaring an observation as influential?

Comment: Hi. Thank You for Your interest. The criteria are default for the analysis (cooks d, dffits or the hat value).

Comment: Yes, but what cut-offs are you using and what is their justification?

Comment: Hi mdewey, thanks again for responding. It was based on this (5.4.2.2.6):

https://bookdown.org/MathiasHarrer/Doing_Meta_Analysis_in_R/heterogeneity.html#hat-value-and-study-weight

Comment: So the critical value of hat is 3/k which is 0.5. I do not see many if any hat values in your plots greater than 0.5.

Comment: I think that one metric beyond cutoff value is enough to have labeled an observation as influential. Thats why there are many observation labeled influential. Do You think that it is statistically correct?

Comment: https://xkcd.com/882/